# Firing projectile in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, projectile

I am trying to make the character fire some waves through the weapon when you click the mouse button, but somehow the waves (projectiles) are not showing in the screen even though the hierarchy shows that its being cloned. I'm new to Unity so I don't understand what's the problem.

This is the code I'm using:

```cpp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject projectile; 
  public Transform shotPoint;

  private void Update()
  {
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
      Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
    }
  }
}
```

I'd be thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: Try double-clicking one of the clones in the editor to zoom the scene view to it. Check where it is, if its visual components are present and enabled, that it’s not the child of a disabled or scaled down GameObject, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try what Sven Viking suggested, but also check the order in layer of the bullet clone. Sometimes it might just be hidden behind another object or the background. Additionally, try setting the speed of the bullet to 0, it might just be that the bullet is moving too fast.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Make sure you're rendering the projectile prefab to the same layer as the camera
- Make sure rendering components are set to enabled
- Make sure that your objects are rendering to the correct z value as I believe that can cause errors rendering

Answer (score 0):

check the size of it and make sure it has rigid body make sure it is textured or that its not invisible and that you are using transform.translate